# How to pass GIT_COMMIT variable to the Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, codeql

I'm unable to find a way to pass the GIT_COMMIT variable to the jenkins pipeline.
There are two steps, first step checks out the repo and second step creates the codeql report. To publish the report I need the recent ccommit id from the repo and pass it in the shell command.

Comment: What is your code for retrieving from git?

Comment: I'm using pipeline syntax generated code for the checkout

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this for checkout step:

```
def scm = checkout(...)
scm.each{ k, v -> env."${k}" = v }
```

All the env variables below will be set and can be used anywhere

```
GIT_BRANCH
GIT_CHECKOUT_DIR
GIT_COMMIT
GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT
GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT
GIT_URL
```